# Remove space before left button on Navigation bar in IOS7?

Tags: iphone, button, uinavigationbar

I can implement navigation bar and add left bar button, but before left button have space, please ask how to remove this space in ios 7.

[image]

Comment: you can refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897470/ios7-excessive-navigationbar-button-padding

Answer (score 4):

use this it will work i have used it and works fine on iOS 7 also

```
UIBarButtonItem *homeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentView];
UIBarButtonItem *negativeSpacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace
                                   target:nil action:nil];
   negativeSpacer.width = -6;// it was -6 in iOS 6  you can set this as per your preference
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:negativeSpacer,homeButton, nil] animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a system `.fixedSpace` `UIBarButtonItem`.

Here is a swift version producing the expected result (iOS 10+):

```
let negativeSpacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
negativeSpacer.width = -20 // working on iOS 10.
let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "<# title #>", style: .plain, target: <# target #> , action: #selector(<# action #>))
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [negativeSpacer, barButton]
```

Another idea is to add a `UIButton` to the `UINavigationController.view` directly.

Comment: why negativeSpacer.width must be -20 ?

Comment: Cause, as it's written in the comment, this is the amount of space on the left of the default button space on iOS 10, so that you have to remove 20px using a negative width fixed space.

Answer (score 0):

We can add customize left bar button of navigation bar, but before left button have space. I fix this issue as following,

**Calling:**

```
//  MyViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad {
        UIBarButtonItem *bbBack = [Utilities overrideBackBarButtonItemWithTarget:self action:@selector(btnBackTapped:)];
}

- (void)btnBackTapped:(id)sender {
    //Custom navigation back bar button item
}
```

Add this class method to your Utilities class or any common class for your project,

**Implementation:**

```
//  Utilities.h

@interface Utilities : NSObject

#pragma mark - back bar button item
+(UIBarButtonItem*)overrideBackBarButtonItemWithTarget:(nullable id)target action:(nullable SEL)action;

@end


//  Utilities.m

@implementation Utilities

+(UIBarButtonItem*)overrideBackBarButtonItemWithTarget:(nullable id)target action:(nullable SEL)action  {

    // back button
    UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 65 , 44)];
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -15, 0, 15);//move image to the right
    [btn addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *barbuttonBack = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];

        //navigation spacer
    UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
    spacer.width = -15;// it was -6 in iOS 6  you can set this as per your preference

        //set leftBarButtonItems
    UIViewController *_self = (UIViewController*)target;
    [_self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:spacer,barbuttonBack, nil] animated:NO];

    return barbuttonBack;
}

@end
```

**Back image:**
[back.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7aQF.png)